# Strip out every occurrence using regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to strip out every occurrence of (title) from a string like below. How do I write a regex for that? I tried a regex like below but it doesn't work.

```
String ruler1="115.28(54)(title) is renumbered 115.363(title) and amended to read:";
Pattern rulerPattern1 = Pattern.compile("(.*)\\(title\\)(.*)", Pattern.MULTILINE);

System.out.println(rulerPattern1.matcher(ruler1).replaceAll(""));
```

Comment: Just use [String's `.replace()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: Do you want to remove "(title)", or do you want to remove the text around it too? If so, what determines the other text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex is much simpler than that - all you need is to escape parentheses, like this:

```
\\(title\\)
```

You do not need to use the `Pattern` class explicitly, because [`replaceAll` takes a regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
String ruler1="115.28(54)(title) is renumbered 115.363(title) and amended to read:";
String result = ruler1.replaceAll("\\(title\\)", "");
```

Your pattern replaces everything in a string that contains `"(title)"`

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/LQpEBo).

Answer (score 1):

Just use what `String` has to offer:

```
System.out.println(ruler1.replace("(title)", ""));
```

DO NOT be fooled by its name vs `.replaceAll()`, it is very misleading:

- `.replace()` does NOT use regexes;
- `.replace()` DOES replace all occurrences.

Given what you need to do, it is a perfect fit. [Javadoc for `.replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Comment: Actually `replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)` uses regex, but escapes its meta-characters using `Pattern.compile(target.toString(), Pattern.LITERAL)` for regex part and `Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement.toString())` for replacement. From String replacing methods only `replace(char oldChar, char newChar)`  is not using regex.

Comment: +1 fwiw this is the best answer. The accepted answer is bad code

Comment: @Pshemo OMG I didn't know that! That seems unbelievable be be frank, and disappointing.

Comment: @Bohemian Yes that was the shock for me to... Maybe if Pattern is compiled with `Pattern.LITERAL` it turns off all unnecessary regex mechanisms. I hope it is implemented this way but never went that deep into Pattern source code. Otherwise String should have simple non-regex based method to replace substrings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think regex is a great solution for something so simple. Try [StringUtils.replace()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#replace%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) from the Apache commons-lang package.

```
String result = StringUtils.replace(ruler1,"(title)","");
```

Comment: Why?? `StringUtils` is not in the JDK, and `String` itself has `.replace()` which does the same...

Comment: String.replace() is not the same.  It doesn't guard against null strings.  It only replaces the last occurrence (not all occurrences)

Comment: While it is not an answer to the question(!), it is a fair point. Using regex in this case is like shooting out of cannon into sparrows.

Comment: WRONG. Read the javadoc. It _does_ replace all occurrences, but it _does not_ use regexes. This is an ultra common mistake.

Comment: You're correct, I misread at first glance, but it does not handle null strings, where stringutils will.

Comment: If you count on stringutils to handle nulls, you have other problems ;)

Comment: Disagree.  It depends on the need.